# Getting sensor data wirelessly from arduino to PC

Tags: serial, xbee

I am working on a project that involves sending motion sensing data wirelessly from an arduino to computer. Sensor readings have to be transmitted continuously (say every mili second). I am not sure if Xbee is my bet. I came across [this link](http://www.faludi.com/projects/common-xbee-mistakes/p://)
which suggest s that there should be atleast 10 ms delay between packets if you're using xbees.

What are your experiences with xbees? I don't want to waste money.

Comment: what is the distance between devices?

Comment: Not more than 5 - 10 meters I think.

Comment: if you don't want to waste money take bluetooth adapter. HC-06 is around 4$. Also there are NRF24L01+ 2.4GHz trasceivers. They are cheap and fast

Comment: How *much* data do you need to transmit every millisecond? I like the nRF24l01+ units and have found them reliable at ranges around 10-15 metres but they have a max payload of 32 bytes and top speed of 2Mbps, both of which will limit throughput.

Comment: I can connect atmost six sensors to the arduino. So It should be around 20 bytes tops. What do you guys think about xbees? I know I can get those easily in my country. Not entirely sure about nRF24l01+.

Answer (score 1):

Xbee costs about 1000INR. They are really expensive. You should buy HC-05 module, which costs about 320INR.
You can easily interface them with Bluetooth of your Laptop using Processing Application.

You can even use ESP8266 ESP-01 Wireless Module. They Cost about 3$.
Wireless module gets connected with your router. [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Wifi-Temperature-Logger/) tutorial will help you to start. You can by this module from [here](http://www.banggood.com/ESP8266-Remote-Serial-Port-WIFI-Transceiver-Wireless-Module-p-947259.html?p=IY04239401772014128X).

nRF24l01+ modules can not be interfaced with Laptop...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion but I am specifically looking for a rf or wifi solution

Comment: ESP8266 ESP-01 Wireless Module is a WiFi solution to your problem!!